# How can I debug a PHP CLI script with xdebug?

Tags: cakephp, xdebug, php

I haven't quite figured this out. EVERY piece of documentation I've found covers how to use xdebug to debug scripts running in Apache. I need to debug a php CLI script.

So, for instance, how do I pass the XDEBUG_SESSION_START variable in to get xdebug to kick on?

I'm specifically trying to debug a CakePHP shell. So if anyone has any additional insight into that I'd be very appreciative.

Thanks.

Comment: You may also want to look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2288612/how-to-trigger-xdebug-for-a-command-line-php-script

Answer (score 41, accepted):

There is a couple of notes about that in [Xdebug's manual](http://xdebug.org/docs/remote), like, for instance (quoting) :

```
export XDEBUG_CONFIG="idekey=session_name"
php myscript.php
```

If you are using Eclipse PDT to develop and debug your PHP scripts, there is not much difference between Apache or CLI : the configuration lloks quite the same, you just don't have to configure a web server, nor indicate an URL ; instead, you have to indicate the path to the PHP executable.

About the `XDEBUG_SESSION_START` variable : well, you launch the whole script in "debug-mode", so you don't have any notion of "debugging-session", I'd say.

For instance, here's what `Window > Preference > PHP > PHP executables` looks like for me right now, and, on the right, what I get when clicking on the `Edit` button of the first one :

[image]
<sub>(source: [pascal-martin.fr](http://extern.pascal-martin.fr/so/xdebug-cli/1.png))</sub>
    [image]
<sub>(source: [pascal-martin.fr](http://extern.pascal-martin.fr/so/xdebug-cli/1-edit.png))</sub>

And the `debug configurations` window :

[image]
<sub>(source: [pascal-martin.fr](http://extern.pascal-martin.fr/so/xdebug-cli/2.png))</sub>

And launching the debugging: it just works :

[image]
<sub>(source: [pascal-martin.fr](http://extern.pascal-martin.fr/so/xdebug-cli/3.png))</sub>

Hope this helps :-)

Else, what specific problem do you encounter ?

Answer (score 9):

If you're using bash (or similar shell), this little script might come in handy:

```bash
alias drush-debug=drd
function drd {
    export XDEBUG_CONFIG="idekey=cli_session"
    export SERVER_NAME="developer.machine"
    export SERVER_PORT="9000"
    drush "$@"
    unset XDEBUG_CONFIG
    unset SERVER_NAME
    unset SERVER_PORT
};
```

or as suggested by the commentators below

```bash
alias drd='XDEBUG_CONFIG="idekey=PHPSTORM" drush "$@"'
```

This way you don't have to manually set and unset the trigger variable each time you want to debug.

Comment: This is logically equivalent to putting the environment variable on the same line as the command in bash, i.e.: "XDEBUG_CONFIG='idekey=cli_session' drush $*".   There's no need for a function which sets and then unsets the variable, the shell will export the variable automatically to the command.

Comment: @Stabledog This, however, if they're not unset xDebug will be enabled for all subsequent drush commands in the current shell, if I'm not mistaken. The idea behind this function was to temporarily enable PHP CLI debugging, but it has its caveats.

Comment: @Plamen use `drush "$@"` instead.  bash will expand each argument with quotes so that `drush-debug cc "theme registry"` would work.  It's not the most intuitive aspect of bash, but it's nice to have.

Comment: @Stabledog I'll take your word for it. However, I find it much easier to type `drd` instead of prepending a bunch of variables each time the command is invoked.

Comment: @Stabledog is correct: all you need is `alias drd='XDEBUG_CONFIG="idekey=PHPSTORM" drush "$@"'`. Note there's no semicolon between the variable assignment and the drush call. The variable will be set only for the duration of the drush call and will not be exported to the shell.

Answer (score 4):

simply put the following section to your php.ini

```
[XDebug]
xdebug.max_nesting_level = 200
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
;xdebug.profiler_enable=1
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
```

and replace PHPSTORM with your ide key

Answer (score 1):

For Windows and Visual Studio Code here's how to proceed:

1. Download xdebug from https://xdebug.org/download. For example php 7.4 Windows 64bit https://xdebug.org/files/php_xdebug-2.9.5-7.4-vc15-nts-x86_64.dll
2. Copy the xdebug dll to your php extensions dir (ext).
3. Add to the end of php.ini

```
    [XDebug]
    zend_extension=php_xdebug-2.9.5-7.4-vc15-nts-x86_64.dll

    xdebug.remote_enable=1
    xdebug.remote_autostart=1
```

4. Open VSCode and install https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=felixfbecker.php-debug
5. Open the project workspace in VSCode, go to Run tab, click the cogwheel and add these lines

```
    {
      "name": "listen CLI",
      "type": "php",
      "request": "launch",
      "port": 9000
    },
    {
      "name": "run CLI",
      "type": "php",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${file}",
      "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
      "port": 9000
    }
```

6. Place a break point in the script you want to debug
7. Select "run CLI" and click "Start Debugging"

Happy debugging!

Comment: Thanks for this.  This helped me set up the php.ini that my VSC Powershell was accessing.  It was the "xdebug.remote_enable=1" that the php.ini was missing, after which the debugger worked fine with PHPUnit in my VSC.

Answer (score 0):

PHP configuration:

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.mode=debug
```

On my system it is the file `/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini`. The configuration could be in the main `php.ini` too.

If I want to run a script with XDebug, I pass the environment variable inline:

```
XDEBUG_SESSION=1 php arguments
```