# How to trigger XDebug profiler for a command line PHP script?

Tags: php, configuration, command-line, profiling, xdebug

XDebug offers the configuration directive `xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger` that allows to activate profiling by passing the GET or POST parameter "XDEBUG_PROFILE" when calling a script via HTTP. This is handy if you don't want profiling for ALL of your scripts but only for a few special cases without always changing your PHP configuration.

Is there a way to achieve the same behavior for command line PHP programs? I tried to pass the `XDEBUG_PROFILE` as a command line argument but it didn't work.

In general, profiling command line PHP works well, but I'd like to have the same per-call-flexibility as with a browser and HTTP server.

Comment: Sorry, i am also trying this but i don't get it. What should be in the "XDEBUG_PROFILE" parameter?

Comment: It doesn't matter what is in the Parameter as long as it is present at all.

Comment: Lack of support for an [XDEBUG_PROFILE environment variable](http://bugs.xdebug.org/view.php?id=413) is bug 413 in the XDebug bug tracker.

Answer (score 275, accepted):

You can pass INI settings with the `-d` flag: `php -d xdebug.profiler_enable=On script.php`.

Comment: On *nix based systems, you can make this a bit easier to use by creating an alias, such as: `alias phpp="php -d xdebug.profiler_enable=1"`. That way when you don't want to profile just use `php` and when you do use `phpp`.

Comment: I had to specify which directory I wanted the profiler output to be saved in as well, so this woked for me: `alias xphp="php -d xdebug.profiler_enable=On -d xdebug.profiler_output_dir=."`. That always stores the debug output in your current working directory.

Comment: yeah, I'm under Eclipse and XAMPP in Win7 enviroment. It works.

Comment: On Windows, you may create in your PATH dir a `phpp.cmd` file, containing `php -d xdebug.profiler_enable=On %*` then you can simply run `phpp <args>`.

Comment: You also can add your parameters to the Shebang-command in a file like

`#!/usr/bin/php -d xdebug.start_with_request=On`

Comment: In Xdebug3 this still works, the setting is renamed to `-d xdebug.mode=profile`

Comment: @LarsNyström The setting was renamed in Xdebug v3: you need to use `xdebug.output_dir` instead of `xdebug.profiler_output_dir` now

Answer (score 50):

I got this working on Ubuntu/Netbeans by:

- copying the xdebug config lines from the /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini file into /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
- setting an environment variable with the name of the debug session (you can get this from the query string in the url of the page netbeans launches when you start debugging) the command is: export XDEBUG_CONFIG="idekey=netbeans-xdebug"

Then it's simply a case of starting debugging in netbeans and doing "php myscript.php" at the command line.

Comment: Note: After you're done if you'd like to keep your debugger listening and not trigger it with a PHP command, you can just use: "unset XDEBUG_CONFIG".

Comment: This is actually working for me while the answer above isn't ;-)

Comment: This is about debugging (stepping through the script).  The question was about profiling (analyzing script's performance, what functions take a long time, etc.)

Comment: On WSL,configuring xdebug in `/etc/php/<version>/cli/php.ini` worked for me.

Answer (score 34):

with PhpStorm on remote webserver i use this command:

```
XDEBUG_CONFIG="idekey=PHPSTORM" PHP_IDE_CONFIG="serverName=server_name" php -dxdebug.remote_host=`echo $SSH_CLIENT | cut -d "=" -f 2 | awk '{print $1}'` myscript.php
```

where `server_name` stands for name of the server in PhpStorm project conifuguration

Comment: i added this to .bash_aliases `alias xphp="XDEBUG_CONFIG="idekey=PHPSTORM" PHP_IDE_CONFIG="serverName=example.com" php -d memory_limit=1G -d xdebug.remote_host=`echo $SSH_CLIENT | cut -d \"=\" -f 2 | awk '{print $1}'`"` so when i wanna debug i use xphp instead of php

Answer (score 27):

As described on the [Xdebug Remote Debugging](http://xdebug.org/docs/remote) page, profiling can also be enabled via the `XDEBUG_CONFIG` environment variable by inluding a "profile_enable=1" directive:

```
XDEBUG_CONFIG="profiler_enable=1" php ...
```

For ease of use, the above command line can be written as an alias:

```
alias xphp='XDEBUG_CONFIG="profiler_enable=1" php'
```

The alias can be added to one of your shell's (interactive) startup scripts, such as `~/.bash_aliases` or `~/.bashrc` (as appropriate to your system).

Comment: This one should be the accepted answer as it's the most accessible method.
PHP binary might be wrapped, it might be set as interpreter #!/x/php at places you don't want to touch.
Using the env variable it can be selectively enabled

Answer (score 12):

Similar, but different process for getting it to work with Netbeans while developing on a VM.

Need to pass in the remote enabled flag, the auto start flag, the ide flag, and the name of your remote host.

```
php -dxdebug.remote_enable=1 -dxdebug.remote_autostart=On -dxdebug.idekey=netbeans-xdebug -dxdebug.remote_host=NAME.OF.HOST script.php
```

Answer (score 6):

## For Xdebug 3

Now enabling Xdebug for a single script would easily be accomplished using the `XDEBUG_MODE` [environment variable](https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#mode):

```
XDEBUG_MODE=profile php script_to_be_profiled.php
```

Answer (score 4):

I created a shell script to handle client debugging.

script name: phpdebug

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh
php -dxdebug.remote_host=`echo $SSH_CLIENT | cut -d "=" -f 2 | awk '{print $1}'` $*
```

I placed this script in `/usr/bin` and gave it execute permissions.

The script takes the arguments passed into phpdebug and calls php with the xdebug arguments and appends the arguments passed into the shell script, the $* on the end.

Comment: Yes, in my case anyway, all I needed was to add the INI setting for my remote host. That was all that was required to do debugging in my IDE from a PHP CLI command.

Comment: Actually, I did also need to set the `XDEBUG_CONFIG` environment variable. Just that and the `xdebug.remote_host` setting made it work.

Answer (score 2):

In PhpStorm 7 using WAMP I got this to work by copying my already working xdebug settings from C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.2.22\bin\php.ini to the xdebug section of C:\wamp\bin\php\phpX.Y.Z\php.ini. Then I ran my script like so:

```
php -d xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM script.php
```

This even worked for debugging laravel artisan scripts

```
php -d xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM artisan db:seed --force
```

Answer (score 1):

[Documentation from Jetbrains](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/debugging-a-php-cli-script.html)

To start the script with debugging using PHP command line switches
Set an environment variable that would tell XDebug to connect to IDE:

Windows / MacOS / Linux

```
export XDEBUG_CONFIG="idekey=123"
```

Here idekey should have a random value.

Launch PHP with the following command-line options:

```
php -dxdebug.remote_enable=1 -dxdebug.remote_mode=req -dxdebug.remote_port=9000 -dxdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1 -dxdebug.remote_connect_back=0 path/to/script.php
```

You may use 10.0.2.2 instead of 127.0.0.1 with Vagrant (see related SO question).

Answer (score 1):

I needed to add the following to my `php.ini`:

```
xdebug.mode=debug
```

https://xdebug.org/docs/step_debug#configure

And the following to my `.zshrc`

```
export XDEBUG_SESSION=1
```

https://xdebug.org/docs/step_debug#activate-debugger-cmd

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to xdebug 3!

It is now:

```
xdebug.mode=profile
```

therefore:

```
php -d xdebug.mode=profile script.php
```