# Visual Studio code(using C#): While putting debugger point then showing me "No Symbol loaded for this document"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, asp.net-web-api

I am using `Visual studio Code` (Stable Version) with `.Net Core 1.0 RTM`. I also Installed `C#` extension for Visual studio Code & .Net Core . Now I am developing `Web api`  and application running fine but I want to debug my code. when I am putting break-point then it is not working and showing me error on break-point mouse hover "No Symbol loaded for this document". Kindly help me . 
I tried following solution :

[Visual Studio Code - Debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30404212/visual-studio-code-debugging)

https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/debugging

Constraint :- I do not want to use mono framework.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Finally I got the solution . If you want to debug dotnet core project using visual studio code then facing this kind of problem then just add `"debugType": "portable"` at `buildOptions` into `project.json` file.

Comment: This fixed the issue for me too. Documentation is here: https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/wiki/Portable-PDBs#net-cli-projects-projectjson.

Comment: In my case the error was with <Optimize>true</Optimize> csproj file, once I switched to false it started breaking.

Comment: now it's <DebugType>portable</DebugType> in csproj