# How to run PHP code from Visual Studio Code (VSCode)?

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

I can't find a way to run php on Visual studio code, Does anyone know how?

**Duplicate:**

Yes it is but a little bit different from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29960999/how-to-run-or-debug-php-on-visual-studio-code-vscode).

**Steps:**

I followed below steps to configure php in VS Code.

1. Configure PHP linting in user settings
   [image]
2. Install Php Debug extension in VSCode
3. Then configure php.ini file
   [image]
4. Create a external php file in root folder
5. add `<? echo "My First PHP site in VSCode."; ?>` in external php file which I created now
6. In my index.html file I referenced my php file like:
   [image]
7. Run my web server apache using xampp control panel
8. Build my project and run it on web browser it shows me nothing.
9. Also when I open dev tools of my chrome browser its shows me my php code of index file commented. why? I don't know.
   [image]

**Question:**

What I am doing wrong in my above steps to configure php in vs code. Please explain me in easy steps so I can easily achieve my goal. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If your problem is getting php files to work on a localhost on Windows just follow the MS instructions [Install IIS and PHP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/scenario-build-a-php-website-on-iis/configuring-step-1-install-iis-and-php). It's simple and Windows takes care of handling the install without you having to find downloads. I followed the part that uses Turn Windows features on or off.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you in fact don't *want* to run PHP from Visual Code, but instead you're trying to get PHP to work at all.

> 4. add  in external php file
>      which I created now

You're using short tags *and that's ok*, if your configuration allows it, however I would recommend using explicit PHP tags: `<?php echo "My First PHP site in VSCode."; ?>`

> In my index.html file I referenced my php file like:

There's the problem. You're placing PHP code in a HTML file. PHP code in HTML files won't be (at least by default) executed. **Change the filename** from `index.html` to `index.php`.

*That should do it.*

Comment: I appreciate your reply. Second thing what I am doing wrong is as you can say that I put above code in my html file. Yes Exactly what I did it. when I changed my file name from .html to .php and put my php (project folder) inside htdocs then finally my php website run. 3rd thing if I run my php code from .html file I search it on net and got a solution by creating an file ".htaccess" and put these code inside it `AddType application/x-httpd-php .htm .html` so my website and server side code easily be access from html file. Again thanks for your answer.

Comment: No problem, I'm glad I could help. However I would discourage you from using `AddType` directive to tell Apache to run your `html` files as PHP. It's good to have them separated. Just use `.php` extension for dynamic pages and `.html` for static ones. At adds security from unwanted code execution and it also saves your server a little bit of performance, because it won't have to run **every** page through PHP processor.

Answer (score 0):

For running simple php website below are the two short steps

```
1. In VS code install PHP debug extension


2. From terminal run the command

    php -S localhost:8080
```