# Assign keyboard short-cut to build task

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

First of all its not duplicated because I have checked  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39067908/how-to-run-php-code-from-visual-studio-code-vscode)  link  first, but it's unrelated.  I have just started using `vscode`.  It very complicated even more if you have  poor english like me .I have searched for related videos on youtube .But they are for mac, mostly .I am using windows  so..

I have follwed theese steps

**Tasks->ConfigureBuildTasks**
and then added theese lines .This is how tasks.json file looks like .

```
{

    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {

            "version": "0.1.0",

            "command": "chrome",

            "windows": {

                "command": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe"

            },

        "args": ["localhost\\${workspaceRootFolderName}\\${fileBasename}"]

        }
    ]
}
```

So..there is no shorcut .. I have no idea how to launch a php file on browser.Any shortcut or key binding

Comment: Do you need to open the file for display-purpose, or only "invoke" it, i.e. have it's php-script executed? For just "invoking" it, I recommend a tiny powershell-call, like this: `powershell.exe -Command "(New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadString('http://localhost/fileToExecute.php')"`

Comment: thank you for letting me know this powershell thing.I am new to programming but ı will check this out But ı am really obssesed with this shortcut :))

Comment: Do you mean the task runs fine from "Tasks/ Run Task..." menu and your only issue is to assign a keyboard short-cut?

Comment: I think so ::) why is that