# How to configure xdebug stacktrace to link to and open files in VS Code

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, xdebug, visual-studio-debugging

When xdebug provides a stacktrace, it can create links to open files in your text editor at a particular line.  For instance, the following configuration will open files in Sublime, if the subl handler is installed:

```
xdebug.file_link_format="subl://open?url=%f&line=%l"
```

How does one set file_link_format for VS Code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the documentation of the [URL format for VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line#_opening-vs-code-with-urls).

Thus, the xdebug config is:

```
xdebug.file_link_format="vscode://file/%f:%l"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the VS Code [Insiders](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/) preview, you can launch using:

```
vscode-insiders
```

So, the php.ini settings become:

> xdebug.file_link_format="`vscode-insiders`://file/%f:%l"