# How to debug websocket application

Tags: php, websocket

I have a chat application with websocket.
How can I debug? I want to set a breakpoint and want eclipse to 
stop at this breakpoint.
The problem is my XDebug is working with port 9000. The websocket server is port 1414.
Is it possible to work with XDebug?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to debug the websocket PHP script (I'm assuming your websocket app is a PHP script) like any other PHP script.

Here's another question that covers debugging PHP scripts with Eclipse from the command line:

[How can I debug a PHP CLI script with xdebug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1947395/how-can-i-debug-a-php-cli-script-with-xdebug)